# Why this c++ template code got "expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token" error?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

The code is meant to solve this problem: If we know a signature and bind params for the first n params, get the new call signature if first n params are bounded.

But gcc gives error when I try this compile the code.

```
a.cc:23:62: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
     using signature = typename GetSignature<R(Args...)>::Bind<BArgs...>::signature;
```

I have no ideal why there is such error.

Here is the code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct GetSignature {
  using signature = typename T::signature;
};

template<typename R>
struct GetSignature<R(void)> {
  template<typename... Args>
  struct Bind {
    using signature = R(void);
  };  
};

template<typename R, typename Arg, typename... Args>
struct GetSignature<R(Arg, Args...)> {
  template<typename... BArgs> struct Bind;

  template<typename BArg, typename... BArgs>
  struct Bind<BArg, BArgs...> {
    static_assert(std::is_same<Arg, BArg>::value);
    using signature = typename GetSignature<R(Args...)>::Bind<BArgs...>::signature;
  };  

  template<typename BArg>
  struct Bind<BArg> {
    using signature = R(Args...);
  };  
};

int func(bool, double, int, char);

int main() {
  // GetSignature<func>::Bind<bool, double>::signature should be int(int, char)
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce on GCC, possibly an MSVC error? [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/e844hv)

Comment: Please provide the gcc version (output of `gcc --version`), and the arguments you pass to gcc other than the name of the file.

Answer (score 2):

I compiled your code by simply replacing this line

```cpp
using signature = typename GetSignature<R(Args...)>::Bind<BArgs...>::signature;
```

with this

```cpp
using signature = typename GetSignature<R(Args...)>::template Bind<BArgs...>::signature;
```

You should use *template* keyword before **Bind** to treat it as a dependent template name.

And after that I can use your template class like this:

```cpp
GetSignature<decltype (func)>::Bind<bool, double>::signature
```

I have gcc version 10.2.0 on my machine.

Comment: thank you very much. Actually I tried template before but I added on the left of = sign.